# NodeJS Loopback - How do I filter models by its relations

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have an EUser model with a belongsTo relationship with userRole. I want to retrieve all the EUsers that have `userRole.codeName == "Admin"`

I can't find an example in the documentation for something like this...

What I've tried so far:

```
server.models.EUser.find({
    include: {
        relation: 'userRole',
        where: {
            codeName: 'Admin'
        }
    }
}, function(err, users){
    console.log(users);
});
```

However this doesn't seem to achieve the correct result.

I have verified that my relationship is defined properly as I can use the "include" filter properly in basic cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't get EUsers, filtered by property of related model, via `EUser.find`.
`Include` filter just adds related models to returned instance.

Try to add userRole hasMany EUser relation as 'EUsers' and find 'Admin' userRole, including related EUser objects:

```
// assuming that userRole hasMany EUser as EUsers
userRole.find({ 
    where: { codeName: 'Admin' }, 
    include: 'EUsers' 
})
```

Comment: Thanks @IvanZh !

Is this the only way? If so, this seems like a strange limitation of Loopback's ORM...

Comment: Yes, for now it's the only way to do this.